# How to install pymba Python library for Vimba on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python

How to install Pymba python package on my Raspberry Pi ?

I am getting this error while importing the package:

> Pymba currently doesn't support i686

Full traceback:

> > > import pymba
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymba-0.1-py2.7.egg/pymba/**init**.py", line 3, in 
> > >           from .vimba import Vimba
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymba-0.1-py2.7.egg/pymba/vimba.py", line 4, in 
> > >           from .vimbadll import VimbaDLL
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymba-0.1-py2.7.egg/pymba/vimbadll.py", line 66, in 
> > >           raise ValueError("Pymba currently doesn't support %s" % os.uname()[4])
> > >       ValueError: Pymba currently doesn't support i686

Comment: If your Raspberry is a i686 system, then I guess the message is straightforward: you cannot.

Comment: If you can install Vimba on the RPi then the pymba library should in theory be able to support it as it's just a wrapper for the Vimba libraries, but perhaps not in it's current state. Does Vimba itself install ok?